# Convert Benjamini-Hochberg FDR Threshold to Adjusted Pvalues

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

Based on what I have learned (and also this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate as well as the original 1995 paper), BH procedure requires specifies a FDR-value threshold. However, I have seen reported raw "adjusted pvalues" that simply adjust pvalues using BH, without specifying the procedure a FDR threshld. How precisely is this done without specifying the FDR threshold?
(Previously asked here: [What's the formula for the Benjamini-Hochberg adjusted p-value?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238458/whats-the-formula-for-the-benjamini-hochberg-adjusted-p-value) but with no answer)

Comment: I think you will still need to specify FDR threshold and get the q-value. The `qvalue` R-bioconductor package can do that for you.

Comment: http://genomine.org/papers/Storey_FDR_2011.pdf has the formula for the q-value.

Comment: The p.adjust package in R adjusts the pvalues without any FDR threshold supplied.

Comment: I just answered the original question (would it be useful to replicate it as an answer to this question?): https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/349686/112049