# Q-value for FDR correction in R stats package

Tags: r, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate, critical-value

I used [FDR correction](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html) (i.e., Benjamin-Hochberg tests) from the R 'Stats' package, but I'm confused of the q value used in the package. The notations in the 'p.adjust' function does not include the default setting for q values, which makes me feel a little less confident. For example, here is my original p-value list:

```
 p_raw <- c(8.133371e-04, 2.471103e-01, 3.343610e-03, 2.505031e-03, 2.887362e-06, 5.736712e-19, 8.955674e-03, 1.199260e-02, 7.698829e-04, 3.301545e-02, 1.126950e-03, 9.405598e-03)
```

Here is my R code for adjusting p-values:

```
p_adjust <- round(p.adjust(p_raw,method="BH"),3)
```

Here is the output for p_adjust:

```
0.002 0.247 0.006 0.005 0.000 0.000 0.013 0.014 0.002 0.036 0.003 0.013
```

I tried to calculate q values using the [formula](https://www.statisticshowto.com/benjamini-hochberg-procedure/#:%7E:text=The%20Benjamini%2DHochberg%20Procedure%20is,reject%20the%20true%20null%20hypotheses.) p_adjusted = (i/m)*q where i is the rank and m is the number of tests but did not get consistent q values for each p_adjust output. I wonder if anyone knows how the R 'Stats' package calculates this and what q value is the package using?

Comment: Type in `p.adjust` with no parentheses and press Enter to see the source code of the function.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. I will update what I found in the formal answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P-values never use set significance levels as part of their computation.
In fact, the lack of reliance on any binary cutoff is part of the attraction of p-values.

In the case of `p_adjust <- p.adjust(p, method="BH")`, the elements with `p_adjust < q` for any value of $q$ are exactly the same elements that the original Benjamini-Hochberg (1995) method would choose as significant in order to control the FDR below $q$.
So the adjusted p-values and the original BH method are exactly equivalent.

Note that it is not sufficient to simply compute `p_raw * m/i` to get adjusted p-values, because those values are not generally monotonic in the original p-values.
It is necessary to apply an extra step to enforce monotonicity.

For a bit more background, see
https://support.bioconductor.org/p/49864/
and
[What's the formula for the Benjamini-Hochberg adjusted p-value?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238458/whats-the-formula-for-the-benjamini-hochberg-adjusted-p-value)

Comment: The links are helpful. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: What if I have performed a backwards stepwise variable selection? How do I apply the p-value adjustment then?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for COOLSerdash's prompt, I looked up the source code for p.adjust in `stats` package. Here is the part that's informative:

```
BH = {
    i <- lp:1L
    o <- order(p, decreasing = TRUE)
    ro <- order(o)
    pmin(1, cummin(n/i * p[o]))[ro]
```

Basically, `stats` uses a formula of `m/i * raw_p` to calculate the adjusted p instead of the traditional `i/m * q`. Therefore, there is no default q value in the R `stats` package FDR correction.

According to the R documentation of this `p.adjust` function, the [original Benjamin-Hochberg (1995) paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346101) was cited to support their method. The original paper used the `p_raw <= i/m * q` correction exactly as the procedure mentioned in this [page](https://www.statisticshowto.com/benjamini-hochberg-procedure/#:%7E:text=The%20Benjamini%2DHochberg%20Procedure%20is,reject%20the%20true%20null%20hypotheses.). Therefore, just multiply the equation by `m/i` we get `p_raw * m/i <= q`. I assume the package uses `p_raw * m/i` to calculate `adjusted p value` and then it's upon us to decide what `q` value to use as criteria. I think it's commonly `0.05` or `0.1`.