# calculating expected value of false discovery rate - Benjamini-hochberg

Tags: p-value, expected-value, false-discovery-rate

I recently got a question that cannot seem to solve, as a beginner in the statistical field.
assume we have 20 tests.
5 with the p-value of 1/330
5 with the p-value of 1/150
10 with the p-value of 1/20

I was asked what are the q-values by the Benjamini-hochberg method?
As well as:
Is there a group of values which is the Expected Value of an error is smaller than 1?

I would really appriciate any kind of help or explanation as i really want to understand those concepts.

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

For example:
I know that q-value is defined as: $q_-value_k = \frac{m*P_k}{k}$
And that it needs to be smaller than $\alpha = 0.05$.
But should i calculated the q-values one-by-one? where do i stop?
the q-value for the first ranked p-value is:
$\frac{20*P_1}{1} = 20*P_1 = 20*0.00303 = 0.0606$
Which is bigger than $\alpha$ , so should I stop here and say that the p-value is not significant? or should I keep going? and if i do keep going with the calculations, what does it says about my results?

The last p-value of 1/20=0.05 gives a q-value of 0.05, and as it is equal to the value of $\alpha=0.05$ should I say that the all the 20 tests are significant?

I also really struggle with the calculation of the Expected Value as I wrote at the begining of the question, I will be really glad for an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the formula for the Benjamini-Hochberg adjusted p-value?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238458/whats-the-formula-for-the-benjamini-hochberg-adjusted-p-value)

Comment: Hey, This is a great explanation regarding the process of BH method, but I still struggle to understand the concept of the q-values here, i will edit the question to explain where I struggle.