# Why are equally-wide confidence intervals used with the Benjamini-Hochberg correction?

Tags: confidence-interval, multiplicity

This [paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/psyp.12616) says:

> *2. For any p-values that are significant after FDR correction, construct a CI for the corresponding test with coverage $1-\alpha^{'}$, where $\alpha^{'}$ is: $\alpha^{'}=\frac{k}{m}\alpha$.

It also says

> FCR adjusted BH-selected CIs guarantee the expected FCR is less than or
> equal to $\alpha$ if the different tests being compared are independent or exhibit positive regression dependency*.

However, it then states that a problem with such approach is that we don’t have CIs for non-significant findings.
My question is:

Why are we restricted to cases where adjusted CIs have all the same length? If different formulas are used to build adjusted p-values depending on ranking, while doesn’t this hold for CIs? I understand this would make the CI length dependent on other comparisons, but this is already happening by making the CI width depend on the number of significant findings.
For example, if there are 5 tests, the first CI has coverage $99\%$, the second one $98\%$, the third one $97\%$, the fourth one $96\%$ and the fifth one $95\%$. In case some p-values are modified to prevent them from becoming larger than the one following them in the ranking (by making them equal to the following one), why couldn't the same thing be done with the CI? I'm referring to what described here:

*[What's the formula for the Benjamini-Hochberg adjusted p-value?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238458/whats-the-formula-for-the-benjamini-hochberg-adjusted-p-value)
Second, make sure that the resulting sequence is non-decreasing: if it ever starts decreasing, make the preceding p-value equal to the subsequent (repeatedly, until the whole sequence becomes non-decreasing).*

My point is: one could adopt a series of CIs with a decreasing range and, when a p-value is adjusted to prevent it from being larger than the subsequent one, adjust the corresponding CI in the same way.

Comment: It doesn't look to me as though the CIs have the same length, as the coverage changes with $k$.

Comment: What I mean is: suppose there are $5$ tests that are passed out of $10$. Then, the CIs all have coverage $97.5\%$.

Comment: Well sure, because they are designed that way.  Why would you want it otherwise?  Saying "some significance tests in my set are at one level of confidence, others are at a different LOC, and it depends upon which ones are most significant" is going to be hard to justify.

Comment: Because I would find it more consistent with what is done with p-values: single p-values are modified according to their ranking (with only the last one in ranking not altered), so I wonder why the same doesn't happen with confidence intervals.

Comment: Remember that B-H adjusts the p-values because it is using the adjusted rates to bound *false discovery rates*, not "create new p-values".    The $\alpha$ used for FDR isn't a confidence interval - type $\alpha$ at all.  We might well be willing to have, say, 20% false discoveries -> $\alpha = 0.2$, but you would almost never consider $0.2$ as a reasonable level of confidence for hypothesis testing.

Comment: I am aware that the BH correction was presented and justified as a way to control for the expected FDR. Nevertheless, a crucial convention is that, when all null hypotheses are true and accepted at the same time, the FDR is 0. This implies that, when just 1 test is performed, the expected FDR coincides with the significance threshold chosen for rejection, and allows reasoning in terms of adjusted p-values for single tests. To be more explicit: when there's just 1 test, if one wants to keep the traditional error-I type probability of $0.05$, s/he also has to chose an expected FDR of $5\%$.